# Asynctask to open a web page in background Android Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm new at Kotlin and don't know how to use Asynctask to open a local web page when clicking a linearlayout (called "giallo"). This page is used to send a message to an Arduino and turn on a light.

This is the intent I've written that opens the page when I click.

```
giallo.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.164/a"))
        }
```

I want this process to be in background.

Comment: There is no reason to start an Activity asynchronously. Whichever Activity handles your intent (in this case a web browser like Chrome) will be the one that takes care of the asynchronous loading of the web site.

Comment: But if you need send a POST request to the IP, you shouldn't be trying to open another activity. Use a web library like OkHttp and it will handle the background work. AsyncTask is deprecated, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You would create an AsyncTask class like this:

```
class OpenWebPage(var main: MainActivity) : AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String): String {
        val url = params.get(0)
        startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
        return "Added"
    }
}
```

And then you would call it like this:
OpenWebPage(context).execute("http://192.168.1.164/a")

More information [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

Comment: There's no reason to use an AsyncTask just to use `startActivity`.